# #1093 - You can't specify target table 'windUpdates' for update in FROM clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete the most lower 60 rows but its not working.
I tried some other posts in stackoverflow but non of them worked for me.

```
DELETE FROM windUpdates 
WHERE INDEX <= ( 
                  ( SELECT MAX(  INDEX )  FROM windUpdates )  - 60
               )
```

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by most lower 60 rows? based on what?

Comment: thats my table for an example:

INDEX 
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
100

I want to delete the rows from 1 to 40 ( 100 - 60 )
100 - the largest number in INDEX colom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create temporary table for the result of your subquery,

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE `Index` NOT IN
(
  SELECT `Index`
  FROM
    (
      SELECT `Index`
      FROM tablename
      ORDER BY `Index` DESC
      LIMIT 60
    ) x
)
```

**PS: Be sure to backup your database first.**

Comment: @user1693118 it has already an alias `x`. [See here for demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09871/1)